# How to change case of matched group text with regex in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: html, regex

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<input type="radio" name="appearance" />
<label>Appropriate</label>
```

I'm using the following regular expression to extract the text within the label tags (not a regex expert, so this works for me, please advice of better way):

```
(<input \btype="radio"\s\b\bname\b="[\w://.]*") \/>(\s+)(<label>(.*?)<\/label>)
```

I'm using the following to replace the code:

```
$1 value=\"$4\"\>$2$3
```

This changes the original HTML to:

```html
<input type="radio" name="appearance" value="Appropriate">
<label>Appropriate</label>
```

However, I want the value, "Appropriate" in this case, to be lowercase. I have tried adding \L with no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need a programming language for that. You can't modify the content of a capture group with just a regex.

Comment: Hi chris85. I'm thinking of copying the code to a more powerful editor like geany and do it there. Then copy it back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in JavaScript, you can just use tolowerCase() in
the callback function.

```js
var input = '\
<input type="radio" name="appearance" />\n\
<label>Appropriate</label>';
     
var output = input.replace( /(<input[ ]\btype="radio"\s\b\bname\b="[\w:\/\/.]*")[ ]\/>(\s+)<label>(.*?)<\/label>/,
     function( m,p1,p2,p3, p4 )
     {
        return p1 + " value=\"" + p4 + "\"\>" + p2+ "<label>" + p3.toLowerCase() + "</label>";
     }
  );
     
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Hi sln. I should probably make my question clearer. What I want to accomplish is to actually modify the code that I have in Aptana Studio. This is at coding time, not running time. I want to use Aptana's editor to do this. Thanks for your idea though. Might come useful later.

Comment: @vasc0x - The above is code that runs at runtime. In your question you state `$1 value=\"$4\"\>$2$3` to replace. When do you expect that to be replaced, at code time ?